# ¿Cómo crear un método dentro de una clase en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

estoy empezando a crear clases en JavaScript y tengo un ejercicio que me pide lo siguiente:

- Crea la clase User con propiedades: username, firstname, lastname, password (cadena vacia por defecto).
- Métodos:

1. En el constructor se pasa firstname, lastname, passwordEn el constructor se pasa firstname, lastname, password
2. username es la primera leta de firstname y las 3 primeras de lastname

Lo que me ocurre es que no se como crear el username. De código tengo lo siguiente:

```
class User {
    constructor(){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.password = password;
    }
    setValores(firstname, lastname, password){
        this.firstname = "Marina";
        this.lastname = "Martin";
        this.password = " ";
        console.log(`El nombre es => ${this.firstname}`);
        console.log(`El apellido es => ${this.lastname}`);
    }
    creaUsuario (username){
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El método slice() devuelve una copia de una parte
> desde (inicio,fin) con fin no incluido El
> original no se modificará.
> Para utilizar la clase necesitas generar una instancia de  ella si la misma no contiene  métodos estáticos que pueden  ser llamados sin instanciar  a la clase
> [apunte de clases](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/programacion-orientada-a-objectos-en-javascript-explicado-con-ejemplos/)
>
> ```js
> class User {
>     constructor(firstname,lastname,password){
>         this.firstname = firstname;
>         this.lastname = lastname;
>         this.password = password;
>     }
>   modificarUsuario(firstname,lastname,password){
>         this.firstname = firstname
>         this.lastname = lastname
>         this.password = password;
>         console.log(` nombre  => ${this.firstname}`);
>         console.log(` apellido es => ${this.lastname}`);
>         console.log(` ahora tiene password => ${this.password}`);
>     }
>     username(){
>         let userName=this.firstname.slice(0,1)+this.lastname.slice(0,3)
>         console.log(userName);//FMar
>         return userName
>     }
>     
> }
> // crear una instancia de la clase User
> const usuario1=new User('Marina','Martin',''); 
> console.log(usuario1)
> // Si se quiere modificar datos de la clase
> let usuario1Modificado=usuario1.modificarUsuario('Francisca','Martin','mar01')
> // obtener username
> let obtUserLetras=usuario1.username();
> console.log(obtUserLetras)//FMar
> ```